# CSS : How to nest grids into grids using grid-template-areas?

Tags: css, css-grid

I try to achieve that : [image]

Using CSS grids templates.

I easily could achieve the template without the "cams" element:

```
#chatContainer {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    grid-template-areas:
        "header header header header"
        "chat chat chat users"
        "footer footer footer footer";

    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 350px;
    grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 50px;
    grid-gap: 0;
}
```

But I have no idea how to "inserts" cams into the chat : looks like I need to nest grids into grids

Answer (score -1):

In the given diagram, all of cams, chat and footer take up just 3 columns and users takes up the 4th column.

So the grid template areas are:

```
grid-template-areas:
    "header header header header"
    "cams cams cams users"
    "chat chat chat users"
    "footer footer footer users";
```

Here's the snippet:

```css
#chatContainer {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-template-areas:
        "header header header header"
        "cams cams cams users"
        "chat chat chat users"
        "footer footer footer users";

    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 350px;
    grid-template-rows: 50px 50px 1fr 50px;
    grid-gap: 0;
}

.item1 { grid-area: header; }
.item2 { grid-area: cams; }
.item3 { grid-area: users; }
.item4 { grid-area: chat; }
.item5 { grid-area: footer; }


#chatContainer {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#chatContainer div {
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="chatContainer">
  <div class="item1">Header</div>
  <div class="item2">cams</div>
  <div class="item3">users</div>  
  <div class="item4">chat</div>
  <div class="item5">footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Anyone know why this was marked down as it actually solves the problem, assuming of course that the viewport is wide enough to accommodate the fixed widths that were specified in the question.